# Properly use csv reader function

Tags: python

When I work with my ip_list function near the bottom, I create a variable and call the function, which is what I expect to do.

When I work with my csv_dict_reader function, I can't figure out a way to assign it to a variable, so do I work with the used_ips variable to manipulate the list in the function? I'd like to compare it to the b variable to look for duplicates.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ipaddress
import csv

used_ips = []
ips = []

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
   reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj,delimiter=',')
   for line in reader:
      used_ips.append(line["ip_address"])
   return used_ips

def ip_list(network_addr):
   addr = ipaddress.ip_network(network_addr)
   for i in addr.hosts():
      ips.append([i])
   return ips

def check_match(a,b):


if __name__ == "__main__":

   with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
      csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
b = ip_list('192.168.1.0/24')

print(b)
print(used_ips)
```

data looks like this:

```
server,purpose,ip_address
server1,SQL,192.168.1.200
server2,web,192.168.1.210
server3,AD,192.168.1.220
```

Comment: Could you submit a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: I don't see how `csv_dict_reader` is doing a different kind of thing from `ip_list`.

Comment: Edited above with a sample of the CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First, bring your variable initializations into the scope in which they operate (and remove them from the base scope). This isn't strictly necessary in this particular example, but is much better practice.

```
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    used_ips = []
    ...

def ip_list(network_addr):
    ips = []
    ...
```

Then, just like you do with `ip_list()`, assign the return value of `csv_dict_reader()` to a variable:

```
with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
    csv_ips = csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

print(csv_ips)
```